# Question for Linear opto isolator circuit

Tags: opto-isolator, linear

-I want to have the same potential or linearity in opto isolator's input and output

- Pic below there is my previous circuit ,sketch and Changed Sketch(the last pic),but it's not linear with PC817.
- I have thought about using HCNR201,TI staff recommend me to use AMC1311,but i don't know how to used it .
- Hope all kind of advice and suggest or recommand another IC for it

Thanks All First

[image: Pervious PC817 circuit]

[image: Previous Sketch]

[image: Current Sketch]

Comment: Follow the App note. http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sbaa229/sbaa229.pdf

Comment: You can also use  IL300

Comment: What is the upper frequency of interest?  What accuracy do you need?

Comment: Look [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/365054/how-to-transfer-0-v-5-v-across-galvanic-isolation-barrier/365277#365277)

Comment: In case you overlooked cost or BW , a Microchip serial ADC is cheaper  with a digital optoisolator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to have the same potential or linearity in opto isolator's
>   input and output

You do not seem to be aware that potential and linearity are not remotely the same thing. And linearity is your problem.

If you go to [the data sheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/73758.pdf) and look at Figure 6, you will see why your circuit does not work the way you want. The CTR is not remotely constant. With non-constant CTR, the current out is not proportional to the current in, so your circuit is wildly non-linear.

If you want to take your chances, get two of the same model and date code, and try replacing your optocoupler with

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3KDel.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There is no actual guarantee that the two units will have exactly the same CTR curves, but you can at least give it a try. With the same model numbers, the CTRs should be something close, and you can vary R2 to do a first-order gain matching.

Comment: They have dual emitters in 1 package now  but with 2 there will always be ESR and efficacy mismatch in emitters upto(+\-50%max) unless same batch

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 - Yeah, which is why I suggested varying R3 as compensation. As long as the slope of CTR vs current is similar, the matching will sort of work.

Comment: if the CTR ranges from 80~600% how well does the slope match? perhaps it only requires a bit of calibration for gain for small changes in effective loss of emitter follower. I would choose Rb/Re=1 using 10k to reduce effect of hFE and limit variation to LED efficacy at low current so ESR variance is minimized, but then you need more current to get more BW

Comment: Actually, 10k is a good idea due to the peak in the CTR/current peak at about 2-3 mA, which will cause the buffer to latch if you try to go higher. As to slope matching, I have no idea. Certainly LED irradiance and photodiode response slopes are fixed, but I wouldn't want to build a commercial product around my circuit. For somebody who's just learning, though, I thought it would be educational.

Comment: PD's are very consistent and PT's are not due to hFE and LED's are not due to efficacy tolerances spanning as much range as hFE but in the same die with dual emitters are very accurate but still rather expensive

Comment: i have try this circuit but when the input is too low for 0~2V will not be too linear but for 2~6V is great

Comment: maybe i'll try to use IL300 to be it more linear

Comment: @張譯安 - If you notice, I've modified the circuit to ad a 10k resistor to +15. See if that helps.

Comment: I'll try again tomorow. Appreciate for all helps

Comment: I've try the modified circuit  it's kind of same for 0~2V , I think i'll try another IC ，Thank you for all guidance. I learn a lot